# Locale aware sorting in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, collation

My basic problem is that I have users with different locales using a database and I want them to get items sorted in their native order.

My understanding is that it works like this:

When I create the database I need to decide:

- Character encoding (ISO, Unicode, codepage etc):
  This limits what characters can be put into the database
- Physical storage (binary, UTF-8, UCS16 endianess etc):
  This is something I trust the database to take care of
- Equality comparison:
  This is necessary so unique constrains etc work consistent in the database. Normally I only need to decide on case insensitivity ("a" = "A") and accents (è = e). **Will locale matter here?**

All these things (+default sort order) is set up by specifying the collation for each field (where default comes from the database which gets default from the instance)

When a connection is set up to the database, the login's language setting specifies how dates and numbers are displayed etc.

This is where I get into trouble. **Why don't the sort order depend on the locale of the connection?** I can understand that the equality comparison must follow the field specification but sort order?

I know I can do `ORDER BY [Name] COLLATE somecollation` but there are several problems with that:

1. It is easy to forget
2. The SQL is often generated by a tool/framework
3. How do I know what collation to specify?

How do you normally handle this? Client side sorting?

Comment: Indexes can only be sorted in one physical order so following your suggested approach that collation be inferred from the connection's language would mean different execution plans for different languages with varying degrees of efficiency. At least an explicit `collate` clause (should) make it apparent that you are doing something with performance implications.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I (wrongly) assumed that text based indexes were hash/radix based. Don't you get different execution plans for different users anyway (unless you are explicit with schemas etc)?

Comment: Actually language is used as a plan cache key too (as can be seen from `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle)`) so the different plans wouldn't be an issue just the potential for catastrophically different performance.

Comment: Can you give an example of countries/ locations where case insensitivity and accents treatment being different depending on your locale?

Answer (score 0):

database collation tells SQL Server how to treat characters according to language commons.

**Will locale matter here  ("a" = "A") and accents (è = e)**
It depends on your collation settings. ("a" = "A") would be treated as same if your collation was case insensitive (CI). (è = e) would be treated as same if your collation was accent insensitive (ai)

**Why don't the sort order depend on the locale of the connection?**
Because SQL Server has to sort data internally somehow and needs some guide how to do it (collation).